# Cannot set HTTP gem source: "source https://rubygems.org not present in cache"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, rubygems

My ruby version in Windows 7:

```
> ruby -v
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [i386-mingw32]
```

When I list gem system sources I see both, HTTPS and HTTP sources:

```
> gem sources --list
*** CURRENT SOURCES ***

https://rubygems.org/
http://rubygems.org
```

Now I would like to leave only the HTTP source:

```
> gem sources --remove https://rubygems.org
source https://rubygems.org not present in cache

> gem sources --add http://rubygems.org
https://rubygems.org is recommended for security over http://rubygems.org

Do you want to add this insecure source? [yn]  y
source http://rubygems.org already present in the cache
```

Please help me to understand how to get the things done. They must be done.

Answer (score 0):

`gem sources --remove` requires an exact match to allow removing the source. Try changing your first command to `gem sources --remove https://rubygems.org/` (copy/paste directly from the `gem sources --list` output).

Comment: This is an abandoned question. Author has no longer anything to do with the topic and can neither approve nor decline your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the solution by accident.  The remove command is singular, not plural.

```
gem source --remove https://rubygems.org/
```

i.e source not sources.

Comment: This is an abandoned question. Author has no longer anything to do with the topic and can neither approve nor decline your answer.